# Причем здесь лямбда?

Tags: java, терминология, lambda, функциональное-программирование

Анонимные делегаты в Java 8 не являются лямбда-выражениями, т. к. в последних не может быть переменных изменяющих свои значения. Так каким боком тут слово лямбда? Причем здесь лямбда-исчисление? С таким же успехом определение функции можно было бы назвать (неверно) лямбда выражением.

Если я заблуждаюсь, скажите в чем? Не следует ли перестать употреблять слово сочетания "лямбда функция" потому, что это:
1) не лямбда
2) не функция
?

Upd2: Я убрал свое предложение. До добавлю уточнение. Насколько псевдо-лямбда-выражения соответствуют лямбде в настоящих функциональных языках?

Comment: по upd: кому вы предлагаете? не думаю, что здесь есть кто то, кто может внести изменения в спецификации Java, а остальные могут называть, как считают нужным, правда иногда рискуют быть не понятыми другими

Comment: Выражение `x = x + 1` не имеет смысла с точки зрения математики. Предложите отменить/переименовать всю терминологию программирования? А словосочетание _переменная константа_ мозги не клинит (у меня - да)?

Comment: Зачем же так. И в математике x = x + 1 имеет смысл. Это уравнение, не имеющее решения. В программировании это крайне неудачная форма записи оператора присваивания. Не просто так Вирт столько бранных слов о нем сказал. Более удачная версия записи x := x + 1. "Переменная константа" - бессмысленное выражение, в топку его.

Comment: pavlofff, предлагаю всем, чтобы лучше понимать о чем вообще речь и друг друга. Твердить лямбда-лямбда как какое то страшное заклинание - плохая практика. Относительно языка Java - на меня глубокое впечатление произвела известная лекция работника Oracle по оптимизации (забыл его фамилию), в которой создается впечатление, что автор одновременно пьян, под наркотой и выступает в КВН. Если его терминология Java довела до такого состояния, то лучше уж все переводить на "традиционный" язык, чтобы не дойти до такого состояния.

Comment: @Eugene: Да, терминология не очень чистая. Но она устоялась. Вон в ФП используют слово «монада» тоже не по делу. Пусть будет как есть, к ней уже привыкли.

Comment: "В математике" - выражение `x = x + 1` может значить все что угодно, в зависимости от выбора конкретной математики, и например - системы интерпретации. Например, в темпоральной логике имеет место время и изменение состояния объектов. Ну и вообще говоря, вопросы вроде связи happens-before, раз уж тут приплели зачем-то Ш - это во многом именно математика.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что Stack Overflow - неподходящая площадка для распространения своего мнения, даже в форме вопросов.

Comment: Идея хорошая, но не жизненная. Термин уже устоялся и все его (даже кто смысла вообще не понимает) употребляют.

Comment: О, началось давление за мнение правильное, но расходящееся с мнением. Я сам убрал предложение. Оставил вопросы. Так пойдет?

Comment: avp, вопрос в том, насколько оно устоявшееся и насколько java-реализация соответствует оригинальной интерпретации в чисто функциональных языках.

Comment: По upd2: Если мне не изменяет память, лямбды без присваивания есть только в Haskell, где вообще нет присваивания, и в Python, который вообще не относится к функциональным языкам. Не могу ничего сказать только про APL и OCaml.

Comment: Sergey Gornostaev, не совсем понимаю, о каком присваивании идет речь. Есть еще Лисп, Scheme..

Comment: @Eugene об этом "в последних не может быть переменных изменяющих свои значения".  Есть Лисп, ага. Во всех диалектах лиспа, включая Scheme, я могу объявить переменную в анонимной функции и присвоить значение ей или переменной из объемлющей области видимости.

Comment: Sergey Gornostaev, а в неанонимной функции?

Comment: @Eugene тем более.

Answer (score 5):

Так сложилось, что в императивном программировании функцией называют подпрограмму (иногда - подпрограмму которая возвращает какое-то значение), без дополнительных требований к побочным эффектам. А оператор присваивания записывается тем же символом, который используется математиками для отношения равенства. Программирование - не математика, и тут термины могут иметь совсем другое значение. Чтобы привести все названия во всех языках к "правильным" формулировкам, понадобится слишком много усилий, которые в итоге всё равно пропадут впустую.

Можно считать, что используемые в программировании определения в некотором смысле *расширяют* математические: математические функции всё ещё можно представлять в виде функций в понимании языков программирования, а непосредственно после оператора присваивания выражения оказываются равны с точки зрения математики.

Точно так же и с лямбдами - понятие, пришедшее из лямбда-исчисления, обобщили, и теперь оно означает сокращённо записанную функцию с замкнутыми внешними переменными, опционально в форме AST. Бессмысленно писать гневные комментарии - теперь в программировании у терминов "лямбда-функция" и "лямбда-выражение" именно такое значение.

Comment: Каковы основания для утверждения о том, что в "программировании вообще"? Насколько я понял, к т.н. лямбда функциям в Java нет никаких дополнительных требований на переменные, с ними можно делать все то же, что вы обычных функциях. Поэтому в Java т.н. лямбда-функции не удовлетворяют даже тому определению, которое вы написали. Разве в псеводо-лямбда функциях в Java нельзя менять переменные?

Comment: @Eugene а где вы в определении увидели дополнительные *требования*?

Comment: @Eugene неа, нельзя. Да и вообще, использовать внешние изменяемые переменные. Называется *замыкание*.

Answer (score 4):

> т. к. в последних не может быть переменных изменяющих свои значения

Откуда эта цитата? Суть лямбд в том, что у них нет имени и они не завязываются на конкретный идентификатор.

Вообще, можно у [Фаулера почитать](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/Lambda.html) статью старенькую на этот счёт, которая актуальность всё ещё не потеряла:

> Essentially a lambda is a block of code that can be passed as an
>   argument to a function call

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92477/discussion-on-answer-by-suvitruf---).